# Pattern for allowing client delegate to override default behavior

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a C# class that has some functionality that I'd like to allow a client of the class to override.  Specifically I'd like the following:

1. If the client does nothing, they get our default behavior
2. The client can override the behavior and cause our default behavior to *not* be called.
3. The client can override the behavior and cause our default behavior to be called as a pre/post/middle operation.

My current thinking is to:

1. Expose an event that the client would subscribe to if they wanted to override the behavior.
2. Expose a method with the default behavior (that matches the signature of the event): 
   `void DefaultBehavior()`
3. Whenever we attempt to fire the event, if the delegate is null, we call our default behavior method, otherwise, we call the delegate of the event:

   ```
   if (eventDelegate == null)
       DefaultBehavior();
   else
       eventDelegate();
   ```

When the client overrides the behavior they can optionally call our DefaultBehavior method to get the desired behavior.

Do you think this approach will be intuitive enough from the client's perspective?  Or can you suggest any alternatives that might be better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you want your client to override some behavior, why not create a virtual function, an let the client actually `override` it?

It's the straightforward way of accomplishing this. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The client is using my class and the class is not intended to be derived from.  I should have made that more clear.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you should change that and make it derivable.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for the entire class to be derivable (I know, I haven't given enough information).  But you got me thinking that another approach would be for me to expose a property (with setter) that returns a class that is derivable (with virtual methods).  If the client doesn't set this property then they would get our default behavior.  If they did set it, they could pass in derived class and override the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, by `client` you mean some code calling your class, and not overriding your class, assuming you need to do it this way (I agree with @zmbq answer if you can do it that way):

You can make your method have 2 overloads, one with no parameters and another receiving a `Action` object

```
public void methodName()
public void methodName(Action delegate)
```

then in the body of `methodName()` you will call the other method with defaultAction

```
public void methodName()
{
  methodName(DefaultBehavior);
}
```

finally in the second method you just call the delegate passed as parameter, without caring if it's the default or not

```
public void methodName(Action delegate)
{
 delegate();
}
```

the client of your class will see this two overloads and decide wether to use the default or give a custom behavior

**EDIT:**
Ok, last try :), according to your last comment would it work for you to have an instance field

```
private Action behaviorDelegate = DefaultBehavior;
```

Anywhere in your class you can assign to `behaviorDelegate` a different behavior, and then you don't need an `if` statement since the behavior will always be in `delegate` variable whether it is the default or not. It is not a big change but it seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I wasn't clear in my question (sorry).  The method will be invoked at the proper time internally by the class.-- it is not intended to be invoked by the client of the class (that's why I used an event).  I need to allow them to provide me the proper functionality that I will call at a later time internal to the class

Comment: Then you can still use this approach, let me know if i need to clarify something

Comment: I like it, but this approach implies that the client has to explicitly  call the method, and from the question it seems that it is the original class that decides when to call it. The client should only decide whether to accept the default behaviour or to override it.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli.  Correct: that is why this approach would not work in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could (perhaps?) also do it without events:

**Declaration:**

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public delegate string MyDelegate(string testValue);

    public static MyDelegate DefaultBehavior
    {
        get
        {
            return testValue => 
              { 
                 return String.Concat(testValue, 
                                      ", now with 99% more exclamation points!!!!!!!!"); 
              };
        }
    }

    public MyDelegate ModifyString = testValue => 
        { 
           return DemoClass.DefaultBehavior(testValue); 
        };
}
```

**Use:**

```
// first, default:
DemoClass demoObject = new DemoClass();
Console.WriteLine(demoObject.ModifyString("My test string")); 

// now, pure "override":
demoObject.ModifyString = testVal => 
        { return String.Concat(testVal, ", this time with question marks????"); 
        };
Console.WriteLine(demoObject.ModifyString("Second test string"));

// finally, define a delegate that overrides and calls default:
DemoClass.MyDelegate combined = testVal => 
        { return String.Concat(DemoClass.DefaultBehavior(testVal), 
                               ", now we're really tricky"); 
        };
demoObject.ModifyString = combined;
Console.WriteLine(demoObject.ModifyString("Third test string"));
```

**Output:**

```
My test string, now with 99% more exclamation points!!!!!!!!
Second test string, this time with question marks????
Third test string, now with 99% more exclamation points!!!!!!!!, now we're really tricky
```

Comment: Thanks.  This approach seems pretty much the same as my original except without the "event" keyword--which means that the client could completely overwrite the ModifyString delegate (rather than just subscribe/unsubscribe to it).  This wouldn't be better IMO because if you overwrite the ModifyString, you risk overwriting a previous delegate.  By using the event keyword you can protect against this (since it only allows subscribing/unsubscribing--not overwriting the underlying delegate).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a virtual method:

```
public class BaseClass {
   public virtual void Something() {
      Console.WriteLine("base functionality");
   }
}

public class Sub1 : BaseClass {
   public override void Something() {
       // do whatever you want here
       base.Something();  // don't call it at all if you like
       // do whatever you want here
   }
}
```

Comment: This type of behavior is what I want, except the class is not intended to be derived from.